# Flutter can't compile with flutter_webrtc

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to build an application that uses webrtc.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/archer/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.2.6/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCFrameCapturer.m:5:
    In file included from /Users/archer/Work/ldrc/ios/Pods/libyuv-iOS/headers/libyuv.h:15:
    /Users/archer/Work/ldrc/ios/Pods/abseil/absl/types/compare.h:33:10: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
    #include <cstddef>
             ^~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

The weird thing is the sample apps published by webRTC work just fine. So I'm not sure what's causing this. I've deleted .pub-cache and let it rebuild, I've run brew doctor, and flutter doctor shows no warnings.

After some trial and error, this seems to be a conflict of somekind between this and cloud_firestore

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved by following
1) Podfile
   platform :ios, '11.0' <== '9.0'

2) pubspce.yaml
dependencies:
   flutter_webrtc: ^0.2.7